# document.body is showing as null

Tags: javascript

The basic layout of my page is

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      stuff
      <script>
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have a button, and when clicked it creates `firstDiv`, attaches it to `document.body`, then attaches `secondDiv` to `firstDiv`, then attaches an `img` to `secondDiv`.

I then have a `button` that removes the `img` (fine), removes `secondDiv` (fine) but when trying to remove `firstDiv` I get the following error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null`

I'm trying to remove it with the following code (the same way I removed the others)

`document.body.removeChild(firstDiv);`

I've looked around on the internet, and people are saying it happens if code runs without body loading, but I don't understand this since my script is added after everything else, not in `<head>` and the code runs after a button is pressed not straight away.

Edit: here is the function to remove the elements, but I've actually figured it out

```
function closeWindow() {
    document.getElementById('firstDiv').removeChild(secondDiv);
    document.getElementById('secondDiv').removeChild(myImage);
    document.body.removeChild(firstDiv);
}
```

I should have been removing `img` from `secondDiv` before removing `secondDiv` (which does make sense) but I'm not sure why this causes *document.body is null* error

I would be interested to know

Comment: Can you post the full code that does the removals?

Comment: I've added this, and figured it out while doing so, but I'm not sure why it fixed it, or broke it in the first place.